# Wrong credentials when connecting to Docker MySQL container

Tags: docker

New to docker and I'm using [laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock) to set up my environment with a [Craft CMS](https://craftcms.com/) project. I'm able to get it installed and set up, however I'm have an issue when trying to connect to the MySQL container that laradock creates from the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Here's the db related portion in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
mysql:
    build:
        context: ./mysql
        args:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead
            - MYSQL_USER=homestead
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
        - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

Within my `craft/config/db.php` file, I have the following settings:

```
return array(     
  '.dev' => array(
    'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    'server' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'homestead',
    'user' => 'homestead',
    'password' => 'secret',
  ),
);
```

However, I'm getting a `Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php` error.

My question is - when docker creates the MySQL container, I'm assuming it uses the credentials in the `docker-compose.yml` file to create and allow access to that database. If so, as long as my container is running and my credentials from my `db.php` file match with the credentials in the `docker-compose.yml` file, shouldn't it connect?

If I wanted to update the credentials in the MySQL container, can I simply update the values in both files and run `docker-compose up -d mysql`?

Thanks!

Comment: You still miss database host in configuration.

You can:
- link database service to your app service and use database service name as a hostname (in your case 'mysql') in `craft/config/db.php`
- set docker bridge address as your database host and use port mapped to the host (ports section).

Comment: Also note that as you are using volumes to persist your mysql data, the variables in your docker-compose will only be read once, when creating the container. So if you don't get them right the first time, your subsequent changes won't take effect (without wiping the volume). I got stuck on that for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I have run in *kind* of similar issue recently because the containers were started in a "random" order. Maybe this is your issue too don't know for sure.

In a brief this is my case: 
 - two containers `php-fpm` and `mysql`. 
 - Running `docker-compose up -d --build --no-cache` build everything but `php-fpm` finished first so by then `mysql` was doing some stuff for get service ready
 - `php-fpm` application couldn't connect to MySQL server because wasn't ready

The solution use the new Docker Compose version and use 2.1 on the `docker-compose.yml`. Here is my working example:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: docker/php-fpm
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
    db:
        image: mariadb
        healthcheck:
            test: "exit 0"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

The trick: `depends_on` ([check here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson)) and `condition` (check the example).

Comment: Sorry to bother on that but the piece of code shown above shows exactly what I'm not sure about: why do we see for example MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} in the docker-compose.yml file? Where does this ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} is stored? It seems that some people have the password stored in this file in clear. Or does it refer to the .env file? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @nadir In this case I am talking about store the password in plain in the `.env` file however there is better strategies out there this one is the easy one

Comment: Thank you for your answer ReynierPM. By the way, I found the solution. So for any person asking the same question on PhpMyAdmin on top of laradock: host = mysql / user = root / password = root